# passive os fingerprinting Android vs Linux

Tags: android, linux, networking, linux-kernel, nmap

I am aware of the fact that Android is derived from the Linux kernel. I am wondering if there are any nuances in the implementation of their tcp stack.

More specifically, are there any features e.g. which are used by passive OS fingerprinting tools like [p0f](http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/p0f3/), which can be used to differentiate between a Linux and an Android device just by passively sniffing the network traffic?

Comment: Do you happen to have a linux box and an android device? You could use the tool to find out!

Comment: @Kenney Already checked. That tool gives the same result for both.